# CSS style similar to bootstrap's input-group

Tags: forms, css

I'm trying to align a button and email input on a form, similar to bootstrap's input-group but without using bootstrap.

Here is an example of my code https://jsfiddle.net/4xx276uL/:

```
.subscribe form button[type='submit'] {
    color:white;
    background:#3197d6;
    border:0px solid #3197d6;
    min-height:52px;
    min-width:80px;
    height: 62px; 
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding: 5px;
```

}

I'm struggling to see how to align the button with the input?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `div.subscribe > form > button[type='submit'] { position: absolute; margin: 0px; }` It overrides your margin-left and margin-top attributes, because they are not needed when pos=abso

Comment: Thanks that's perfect

Comment: Out of interest, is there a way to achieve this without using absolute position?